# Deleting from database by clicking button

Tags: database, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am creating an app using the SqlLite database. I am able to populate the database with some basic information from the sign-up page and display only the ID of the person under the Login tab (This is for testing purposes for now). How would I go about deleting a specific position in the database by clicking the delete button? here is my cs where I am connecting to my database and using it to display just the Id on the page under a list view.

```
namespace SP
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            using (SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.FilePath))
            {
                conn.CreateTable<SignInInformation>();
                var info = conn.Table<SignInInformation>().ToList();

                userData.ItemsSource = info;
            }
        }

        void DeleteButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SP.LoginPage">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="DeleteButton"
                     Text="Delete"
                     Clicked="DeleteButton_Clicked">
        </ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    
    
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView x:Name="userData">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

> How would I go about deleting a specific position in the database by
> clicking the delete button?

Yu can use [Xamarin.Forms MenuItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/menuitem) to achieve this function.

The Xamarin.Forms [`MenuItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.menuitem?view=xamarin-forms) class defines menu items for menus such as `ListView` item context menus and Shell application `flyout` menus.

You can refer to the following code:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Margin="20" ItemSelected="OnListItemSelected">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Margin="20,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                    <Image Source="check.png" HorizontalOptions="End" IsVisible="{Binding Done}" />
                </StackLayout>

                <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <MenuItem Text="Delete"
                                  Clicked="OnDeleteClicked"/>
                </ViewCell.ContextActions>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Method `OnDeleteClicked` in `TestPage.xaml.cs`

```
    async void OnDeleteClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TodoItem itemToDelete = ((sender as MenuItem).BindingContext as TodoItem);

        TodoItemDatabase database = await TodoItemDatabase.Instance;
        await database.DeleteItemAsync(itemToDelete);
    }
```

For more details, check:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/menuitem .

And there is also a sample included in above doc, you can check it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-menuitemdemos/ .